# Trigger trailing white space on demand on Sublime text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Related with the [third answer from this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297169/sublime-text-2-trim-trailing-white-space-on-demand) I would like to refactor this simple plugin so that it works with Sublime Text 3. Please, could you help me? I am new to python, and I don´t know anything about plugin development for sublime.

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

def trim_trailing_white_space2(view):
    trailing_white_space2 = view.find_all("[\t ]+$")
    trailing_white_space2.reverse()
    edit = view.begin_edit()
    for r in trailing_white_space2:
        view.erase(edit, r)
    view.end_edit(edit)

class TrimTrailingWhiteSpace2Command(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        trim_trailing_white_space2(self.view)
```

I have searched and the problem is `begin_edit()` and `end_edit()`. I don´t want to install a plugin just for triggering trailing white space on demand. Thanks a lot, best regards.

Comment: Sublime has this built in, you can just set `"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,` in settings.

Comment: Yes I know, but I work in a team with people who does not trim trailing white space, so I just want to remove white spaces on my own files. Triggering from a shortcut is perfect.

Comment: If your project doesn't have this convention, I suggest to either enforce it and have everyone set up their editor, or just forget it and not clutter the diffs with unrelated whitespace changes in "your own files". Consistency wins here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working on ST3.

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

    class TrimTrailingWhiteSpace2Command(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
        def run(self, edit):
            trailing_white_space = self.view.find_all("[\t ]+$")
            trailing_white_space.reverse()
            for r in trailing_white_space:
                self.view.erase(edit, r)

    class TrimTrailingWhiteSpace2(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
        def run(self, view):
            view.run_command("trim_trailing_white_space2")
```

Answer (score 1):

In Sublime Text 3 you simply need to map a shortcut for the native trim function. Just add

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+t"], "command": "trim_trailing_white_space" }
```

To your key bindings under `Preferences` → `Key Bindings - User`. It can then be executed by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.