# How to compare two remote files in php?

Tags: php, file, request, remote-server

I want to compare two remote files in php code.Both file behind **CDN**. Please let me know if any one have any idea how to do this.

Comment: what you mean by compare? whether the file content is identical? or compare line by line?

Comment: Yes, i want to check both files have same content or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare checksums of the two files to see whether they contain the same content. You can use [hash_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php) for generating checksums.

Example:

```
$file1 = // path to file 1
$file2 = // path to file 2

$hash_file1 = hash_file("sha256", $file1)
$hash_file2 = hash_file("sha256", $file2)

if ($hash_file1 != $hash_file2){

   echo "File content does not match!"
}
```

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php

Comment: This is not working with different url of same file. Its working if i am pass both file url same. I don't know why.

Comment: My both urls as :--
1) https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js
2) https://static.indianexpress.com/poc/gpt.js
BTW :- Both files have same content

Comment: I checked myself files you linked are not same, so checksums do not match.

Comment: One file is own my server and other is on third party . I can't put both file on my server.

Comment: Can you let me know the difference because i just copied one file into another.

Comment: not able to see space. Have you seen any space at end of file.

Comment: If i put both file on my server then also it is working with different urls.

Comment: there is difference is file size, one is 47, 166 other one is 47, 162. so there is some whitespace added. this  probably your text editor is adding whitespace on save

Comment: Can we ignore white space before generate hash?

Comment: @ThathSingh what is the text editor, you  used to copy and save the file?

Comment: I used sublime 3 text editor.

Comment: chekout: [removing trailing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297169/sublime-text-2-trim-trailing-white-space-on-demand). by the way since the my answer answer your question, please upvote and mark as correct.

Comment: Thanks @user158 for your support. Thank you so much.

Comment: my pleasure, did you figured out the spacing issue?

Comment: I write my file via php code not copy paste file manual. I am glade now it is working fine.Thanks once again.

Comment: additional information for you: sometimes checksums can collide, but it is very rare. you may find [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47809/why-havent-any-sha-256-collisions-been-found-yet) interesting. In general checksums/hashes is security technique used to check whether a file have been tampered or not.

Comment: Thanks for [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47809/why-havent-any-sha-256-collisions-been-found-yet) information.